# Typescript: Initialize Object with Default values from a class

Tags: javascript, typescript

how do I create a typescript class/js that initializes an object with default properties?
currently using a class with typescript parameters

e.g. this is my class

```
export class StateModel {
  stateID: number;
  stateCode: string;
  stateName: string;
  stateTwoCharCode: string;

  constructor(
    stateId: number, 
    stateCode: string = '', 
    stateName: string = '',
    stateTwoCharCode: string = ''){
    this.stateID = stateId;
    this.stateCode = stateCode;
    this.stateName = stateName;
    this.stateTwoCharCode = stateTwoCharCode;
  }
}
```

In the code I import it at, I want to call something like this:

```
let newClass = new StateModel();
```

if I console log `newClass` I expect the following result:

```
newClass = {
  stateCode: '',
  stateName: '',
  stateTwoCharCode: ''
}
```

but ideally I would want the parameters to be optional though to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

you can use optional [parameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html#optional-and-default-parameters), in your code the only thing missing is the private keyboard:

```js
export class StateModel {
  stateID: number;
  stateCode: string;
  stateName: string;
  stateTwoCharCode: string;

  constructor(
    stateId: number, 
    private stateCode: string = '', 
    private stateName: string = '',
    private stateTwoCharCode: string = ''){
    this.stateID = stateId;
    this.stateCode = stateCode;
    this.stateName = stateName;
    this.stateTwoCharCode = stateTwoCharCode;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're code for optional parameter is working. You just need to initiate it like this

```
newClass: StateModel = new StateModel(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=11&pc=32#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GUYpsAWQgBNgk4BvAKDkQgDs0YoBXBGaAChtrjBYBGSAJYI4TPMACSxAFxx6LALYDgUADRwetfkNHjc+AMIlg8plGH0A5nAC8cAOSPN2vpYBukg5IByKJTMDSxt7Jxc3ME9vCXwAFQB3CCMACxQoE1JzZitbB2cASmoeAF8qMqoEBiY4ADMICDD6YATsQ0JTJE4ARgAmAGYCoA

If I write this in typescript

```
export class StateModel {
  constructor(
    public stateId: number, 
    public stateCode: string = '', 
    private stateName: string = '',
    private stateTwoCharCode: string = ''){

  }
}

const foo = new StateModel(123)
console.log(foo,"foo")
```

it compiles to this in javascript

```
export class StateModel {
    constructor(stateId, stateCode = '', stateName = '', stateTwoCharCode = '') {
        this.stateId = stateId;
        this.stateCode = stateCode;
        this.stateName = stateName;
        this.stateTwoCharCode = stateTwoCharCode;
    }
}
const foo = new StateModel(123);
```

logging `foo` shows the intended object structure